# Using Spring "forward:" prefix resulting in StackOverflowError

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm attempting to forward a request received from one Controller to a second Controller using Spring's "forward:" prefix. However, instead of forwarding the request on to the second Controller as I would expect, the request is instead handled by the first Controller over and over again (until I receive a StackOverflowError). This made me think it might be treating the "/app/pong" as a relative path of some sort, but I'm not sure why this would be the case. Am I misunderstanding how "forward:" is supposed to work? Is there something that I'm missing here?

Controllers:

```
@Controller
public class ControllerOne {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/ping", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String doPing(HttpServletRequest request) {
    log.debug("Ping?");
    return "forward:/app/pong";
  }
}

@Controller
public class ControllerTwo {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/pong", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String doPong(HttpServletRequest request) {
    log.debug("Pong!");
    return "pong";
  }
}
```

servlet-mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>test-servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

view resolver:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Comment: what happens if you try with "forward:app/pong"?

Comment: The same thing happens when I try using "forward:app/pong".

Comment: Does it work if you use a redirect: instead of a forward:

Comment: Yeah, if I use the "redirect:" prefix it will get redirected to "/app/pong" but I still don't understand why "forward:" is causing a loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is about the `InternalResourceViewResolver` that you configed. Because the inner logic of this viewResolver, it will do a forward automatically, you can config another kinds of viewResolver: UrlBasedViewResolver .
Below is the information I found in official document:

> It is also possible to use a special forward: prefix for view names
>   that are ultimately resolved by UrlBasedViewResolver and subclasses.
>   This creates an **InternalResourceView** (which ultimately does a
>   RequestDispatcher.forward()) around the rest of the view name, which
>   is considered a URL. Therefore, this prefix is not useful with
>   **InternalResourceViewResolver** and InternalResourceView (for JSPs for example). But the prefix can be helpful when you are primarily
>   using another view technology, but still want to force a forward of a
>   resource to be handled by the Servlet/JSP engine. (Note that you may
>   also chain multiple view resolvers, instead.)